# getting @autowired intance null when try trying to do operation on it,throwing null pointer exception

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I am trying to save data on gemfire using crud repository. I have created one operation class to call save method of repository but at autowired instance I am getting null pointer exception. Below is my code:

```java
public interface GeodeRepository extends CrudRepository<KeyValueBean, String> {

    @Override
    public KeyValueBean findOne(String name);

    @Override
    public <S extends KeyValueBean> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
}

@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = GeodeRepository.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class Operations {

    @Autowired
    private GeodeRepository repository;

    public void saveKeyValueData(KeyValueBean keyValueBean) {
        System.out.println("Repository is : " + repository);
        repository.save(Arrays.asList(keyValueBean)); // <--- i am getting
                                                        // repository as null so
                                                        // getting null pointer
                                                        // exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the class GeodeRepository compiled properly.

Comment: Is the " in "@EnableGemfireRepositories copied from your code? This might be the problem.

Comment: How are you getting an instance of `Operations` and calling `saveKeyValueData` on it?

Comment: Are you creating new Operation to call saveKeyValueData ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we `@Autowired` any class make sure, you have declared that class as a `@Component`.

for example:

```
@Component
public class Operations {

    @Autowired
    private GeodeRepository repository;

    public void saveKeyValueData(KeyValueBean keyValueBean) {
        System.out.println("Repository is : " + repository);
        repository.save(Arrays.asList(keyValueBean)); 
    }
}
```

and try using `@Autowired` to Operation class to your class
in which class your are calling  your `saveKeyValueData()` method.

Answer (score 2):

So, what is not apparent from your example is how you "bootstrap" your application and it's features (e.g. *Repositories*) into action.

It is not simply enough to add the *Spring* `@Configuration`, *Spring Boot's* `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and SD GemFire's `@EnableGemfireRepositories` annotations and expect everything to be auto-configured and wired up successfully.  I.e. you need a bootstrapping mechanism, like *Spring Boot*, especially if you are using the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.

For example...

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
...

class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Operations.class, args);
  }
}
```

Now, you could remove the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your `Operations` class and add the `@SpringBootApplication` to the `MyApplication` class, like so...

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {
...
}
```

[@SpringBootAppliation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) combines together *Spring's* `@Configuration` with *Spring Boot's* `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, along with many other useful meta-annotations, like *Spring's* `@ComponentScan`, enabling all sorts of magic to happen.

But, if you are not using *Spring Boot*, you can always bootstrap you application with the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, like so..

```
class MyApplication

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = 
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Operations.class);

    applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
  }
}
```

This is essentially what the *Spring Boot*, `SpringApplication` class does for you anyway.

If you are developing a Web application, then of course you can specify the type of `ApplicationContext` created since you are using Java config, for instance. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet-sequence) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
John